# Saving to specific core data object in Today Extension

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2

Working on a part of my iOS project that needs to refer to a specific object that the user selects in the main application that is set through a toggle switch that activates the specified object to be used in a Today Extension to record simple objects created by the user in the Today Extension. I am unsure how to go about doing this specifically. I thought about using NSUSerDefaults as the go to method for specifying that object but this is all entirely new to me. Has anyone gone down this path before on here? Does anyone know a way to refer to the specific object you want to store to in the Today Extension?

Comment: Anyone know have any clue on any of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a reference to a specific managed object by using the `objectID` property (an instance of `NSManagedObjectID`), which can be converted to a URI. The URI can then be converted to `NSData`, which you can save in user defaults.

To save the reference, get the object's ID as a URI:

```
let objectIDURI = newManagedObject.objectID.URIRepresentation()
```

Then convert to `NSData` and save:

```
let objectIDURIData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(objectIDURI)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objectIDURIData, forKey: "savedID")
```

To get the object back, load the `NSData` and convert back to an `NSURL` (the following is simplified, you'll have to handle optionals properly):

```
let savedObjectIDURIData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedID") as? NSData
let savedObjectIDURI = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedObjectIDURIData!) as? NSURL
```

Then convert the ID back to an `NSManagedObjectID` and get the managed object:

```
let savedObjectID = context.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(savedObjectIDURI!)
let savedObject = context.objectWithID(savedObjectID!)
```

At this point `savedObject` is the managed object that was saved above.